# HashiCorp Vault 403 Permission Denied issue with Kubernetes Auth

Tags: kubernetes, http-status-code-403, hashicorp-vault, vault

I got two types of strange situations when deploying Vault in Kubernetes and using `Kubernetes Auth` method

> Kubernetes version: v1.25.6
> Vault version: v1.12.1

#### **1. It kept getting 403 `permission denied` from `/v1/auth/kubernetes/login` for about 30 minutes long time before suddenly got desired secrets successfully at `vault-agent-init` stage. Sometime it never got success after even several hours.**

**Error:**

```bash
==> Vault agent started! Log data will stream in below:

==> Vault agent configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
               Log Level: info
                 Version: Vault v1.12.1, built 2022-10-27T12:32:05Z
             Version Sha: e34f8a14fb7a88af4640b09f3ddbb5646b946d9c

2023-04-03T15:42:38.374Z [INFO]  sink.file: creating file sink
2023-04-03T15:42:38.374Z [INFO]  sink.file: file sink configured: path=/home/vault/.vault-token mode=-rw-r-----
2023-04-03T15:42:38.374Z [INFO]  template.server: starting template server
2023-04-03T15:42:38.375Z [INFO] (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
2023-04-03T15:42:38.374Z [INFO]  sink.server: starting sink server
2023-04-03T15:42:38.375Z [INFO]  auth.handler: starting auth handler
2023-04-03T15:42:38.375Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2023-04-03T15:42:38.375Z [INFO] (runner) creating watcher
2023-04-03T15:42:38.381Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:
  error=
  | Error making API request.
  | 
  | URL: PUT http://vault.vault.svc:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  | 
  | * permission denied
   backoff=1s
2023-04-03T15:42:39.381Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2023-04-03T15:42:39.383Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:
  error=
  | Error making API request.
  | 
  | URL: PUT http://vault.vault.svc:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  | 
  | * permission denied
   backoff=1.62s
```

#### **2. Sometime it got authenticated at `/v1/auth/kubernetes/login` soon, but then threw the error like:**

```bash
# (Can't get the output now, but something like this:)
vault.read(myapp/data/postgres/config), vault.read(myapp/data/postgres/config)

URL: GET http://vault.vault.svc:8200/v1/myapp/data/postgres/config
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
```

---

### **How I installed Vault in namespace vault:**

**helm vaules.yaml:**

```yaml
ui:
  enabled: true

server:
  logLevel: trace

  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
  
    raft:
      enabled: true
  
  dataStorage:
    storageClass: cstor-csi
  
  auditStorage:
    storageClass: cstor-csi
  
  authDelegator:
    enabled: true

injector:
  enabled: true
  logLevel: trace
```

```bash
helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com
helm repo update
# Install a spceified version vault in namespace `vault`.
helm upgrade --install vault hashicorp/vault --namespace vault -f vault-values.yaml --version 0.23.0 --create-namespace

# Unseal
kubectl exec -ti vault-0 -n vault -- vault operator init > keys.txt
kubectl exec -ti vault-1 -n vault -- vault operator init >> keys.txt
kubectl exec -ti vault-2 -n vault -- vault operator init >> keys.txt
kubectl exec -ti vault-0 -n vault -- vault operator unseal
kubectl exec -ti vault-1 -n vault -- vault operator unseal
kubectl exec -ti vault-2 -n vault -- vault operator unseal

kubectl exec -it vault-0 -n vault -- /bin/sh

vault login

vault auth enable kubernetes

# Do this as document says:
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
    kubernetes_host="https://$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:443"

vault secrets enable -path=myapp kv-v2

vault kv put myapp/postgres/config POSTGRES_DB="myapp" POSTGRES_USER="myapp" POSTGRES_PASSWORD="myapp"

vault kv get myapp/postgres/config

vault policy write myapp - <<EOF
path "myapp/data/postgres/config" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF

vault write auth/kubernetes/role/myapp \
    bound_service_account_names=myapp-sa \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=myapp \
    policies=myapp \
    ttl=3d

# create sa myapp-sa in namespace myapp, not the namespace with vault.
kubectl create sa myapp-sa -n myapp
```

---

### **Deployemnt of myapp in namespace myapp**

```yaml
# I don't know if this ClusterRoleBinding needed?
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: myapp-sa-rbac
  namespace: myapp
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myapp-sa
  namespace: myapp
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: myapp
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: 'update'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "myapp"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-database-config: "myapp/data/postgres/config"
        # Environment variable export template
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-database-config: |
          {{ with secret "myapp/data/postgres/config" -}}
          export POSTGRES_DB="{{ .Data.data.POSTGRES_DB }}"
          export POSTGRES_USER="{{ .Data.data.POSTGRES_USER }}"
          export POSTGRES_PASSWORD="{{ .Data.data.POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}"
          {{- end }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myapp-sa
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: nginx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          command: ["sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - . /vault/secrets/database-config
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PORT
              value: "5432"
```

Comment: tl;dr; You should not initialize every node of your cluster. There is a race condition that you might be lucky to win, but don't count on it. Initialize the first one, and let it form the cluster (maybe helping it out with a command other than `vault operator init`). And quote the `EOF` marker of your here-doc, like this `vault policy write myapp - <<'EOF'`

Comment: @ixe013 thank you for answering, I tried just initializing the first node `vault-0` and unseal it and waited, but the other two never got initialized automatically then, just acted as before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

We should do `raft join` rather than `vault operator init` for three times:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-minikube-raft

```bash
# Join the vault-1 pod to the Raft cluster.
kubectl exec -ti vault-1 -- vault operator raft join http://vault-0.vault-internal:8200

# Join the vault-2 pod to the Raft cluster.
kubectl exec -ti vault-2 -- vault operator raft join http://vault-0.vault-internal:8200
```